# Is there any facebook api which takes username and password for login?

Tags: android

I dont want to use facebook dialog box for login. Is there any facebook api which takes username and password for login?
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be down-voted simply because the OP is ignorant to app security. It's a pretty valid question for anyone who doesn't understand that topic and who might be looking to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses OAuth for authentication which makes it impossible for you to login a user with their username and password. The whole point is not letting you access user credentials within your application.